# My Sql query is not giving desired output related to Many to Many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is my Student and Batch Table

Student Table

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|Sid|Name   |Address   |Gender|ContactNumber|DateOfBirth|
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| 1 |Mike   |Delhi     |Male  | 986523245   |19900909   |
| 2 |John   |Washington|Male  | 78452356    |19900109   |
| 3 |Garima |Lucknow   |Female| 78659432    |19910903   |
| 4 |Sparshi|Lucknow   |Female| 789456135   |19910410   |
| 5 |Akash  |Jaipur    |Male  | 965478312   |19850905   |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Batch Table

```
+-------------------------------------+
|Bid|BName     |BStartDate| BCapacity |
+-------------------------------------+
| 1 |.NetBatch |2016-10-10| 30        |
| 2 |JavaBatch |2016-12-10| 20        |
| 3 |CCNABatch |2017-01-10| 15        |   
+-------------------------------------+
```

It has many to many relationship. I am creating another table for retrieving data from these table.
I created another table called "StudentBatch" table

```
Create table Student_Batch
         (Stdid int,
          Batid int,
          Std_JoiningDate date,
          Foreign key(StdId) references Student(Sid),
          Foreign key(BatId) references Batch(Bid))


+-----------------------------+
|Stdid |Batid|Std_JoiningDate|
+-----------------------------+
| 1    |  1  |   2017-01-10   |
| 2    |  2  |   2017-01-01   |
| 3    |  1  |   2017-01-20   |
| 4    |  3  |   2016-10-12   |
| 5    |  2  |   2016-09-10   |
+-----------------------------+
```

When I am executing both(Student and StudentBatch) table using Join then I am not getting desired output.
Below is my query :

```
 Select      S.Name,SB.Batid
 from        Student S
 inner Join  Student_Batch SB
 on          SB.Batid = S.Sid
```

And Output is :

```
Name    Batid
Mike    1
John    2
Mike    1
Garima  3
John    2
```

Please correct me where i am doing wrong.

Comment: `I am not getting desired output.` ... What is your desired output?

Comment: First figure out which RDBMS you're using.

Comment: I am using Ms Sql 2014.

Comment: "on  SB.Batid = S.Sid" should be "on SB.Stid = S.Sid"...

Comment: Hey Xavier, Its working now. I was using SB.Batid = S.Sid instead of SB.Stdid = S.Sid. Thank you so much for figuring silly mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hoping, i understood your problem correctly.

I think you are making join with batch id and student id from both tables. However, you have to make join condition with student id's in both tables(Student and Student_batch)

Please check below query

```
Select      S.Name,SB.Batid
from        Student S
inner Join  Student_Batch SB
on          SB.Stdid = S.Sid -- changed
```

Comment: Yes Tajinder, I was doing silly mistake in my query. Its working fine now